# In PHP array assignment throws a strange error

Tags: php

[image]    $form = [];

```
$pdf_link = 'http://localhost:8080/view/123';

$form["pdf_link"] = $pdf_link;
```

The above array assignment throws ParseError for the first time for me. The error as follows:

> syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Don't know what is causing the issue. Can anybody help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to rewrite double quotes to single quotes.

Comment: Nope https://3v4l.org/LbMIn

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the posted code. Please make sure you have copy/pasted the exact code from the file and the line (and some lines before and after) it complaints about in the error message.

Comment: in fact, i added the short version of my code. now, i attached error screen shot.

Comment: Your code does not match the code in the screenshot...

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide that. I'm halfway sure you will find the error yourself doing that. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: try replacing the double quote with a single quote. this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can try it. First, initialize the array then assign value in it.

```
$form["pdf_link"] = null;
$pdf_link = 'http://localhost:8080/view/123';
$form["pdf_link"] = $pdf_link;
```